# Can you detect a debugger attached to your process using Div by Zero

Tags: c, windows, debugging, operating-system

Can you detect whether or not a debugger is attached to your native Windows process by using a high precision timer to time how long it takes to divide an integer by zero?

The rationale is that if no debugger is attached, you get a hard fault, which is handled by hardware and is very fast. If a debugger is attached, you instead get a soft fault, which is percolated up to the OS and eventually the debugger. This is relatively slow.

Comment: I did try it. I think there's a statistical correlation, but you can't reliably use it because it's hard to choose a cutoff threshold for how long it should take on different hardware.

Comment: And what if an interrupt arrived at that moment?  How about a context switch?  At best you will get a probabilistic result.

Comment: Seems more like a discussion element than a straight Q&A.

Comment: Well sure, the first chance exception notification will take tens of thousands of cpu cycles.  Why you'd write code like that is hard to guess when you just could call IsDebuggerPresent().

Comment: If I'm trying to reverse engineer your code, finding all calls to IsDebuggerPresent() and no-oping them is simple.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this question, but it seems to be a real question nonetheless. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Man, I'm glad you spend time insulting people you're asking for help by calling them "nobodies" and being rude. I'd suggest you stop doing so if you want answers to your questions. If you can't accept the constraints of the design here, maybe you should look for help somewhere else.

Comment: Please note that high rep does not give your opinion any more weight when it comes to closing a question...

Comment: This is about anti-debugging techniques?   Not exactly crystal.  The first google hit is excellent: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most debuggers used by reverse engineers come with methods to affect (remove) 99% of the marks left by debuggers, most of these debuggers provided exception filtering, meaning the speed difference would be undetectable.

its more productive to prevent the debugger attaching in the first place, but in the long run you'll never come out ahead unless you make the required effort investment unfeasable.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent a determined person from reverse engineering your code, no clever approach you find will be significantly better than calling `IsDebuggerPresent()`

Comment: To be more specific, the person reverse engineering your code could simply provide a virtualized timer that hides time spent in the debugger...

Comment: ... or just remove whatever it is that you plan to do upon detecting slow division by 0... or just remove the division by zero itself... or just read the disassembled code... or not waste his time on the application that I really doubt is worth reverse engineering.

Comment: Yes, it's quite unclear what's wrong with using the obvious approach here and calling `IsDebuggerPresent`. Someone commented about that, but the asker just got mad and called him a "nobody" instead.

Comment: @CodyGray I think he got mad at people who closed his question and I sort of agree with him (minus the language).  The question is not a great one, but completely valid.  I do not like SO police.

Comment: The "SO police" are the users that keep this site useful, and are the entire design of the site. If multiple users think it's not a valid question, the question gets closed. If more users decide it is, it gets reopened. "SO police" is offensive - they're working in accordance with the site's guidelines. Posting comments like this is inflammatory - if you don't like the guidelines, go somewhere else or suggest a change via [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @KenWhite no, I think saying "love it or leave it" in response to criticism is offensive.  I have raised this and other issues on Meta and realized that majority of people disagree with me and respect that.  However I do not think that this somehow means that I can't continue voicing my dissent.  I am an active member of the community and you can not lecture me like this about the usefulness of moderation.  I regularly vote to close questions that are not a good fit.  This particular one is, in my opinion, a good fit for this site, and I insist that closing this question was a mistake.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that you have to stop voicing your dissent. But it does make sense for you to voice that dissent in the appropriate forum: the Meta site, which you've already discovered. Just as you're free to express your opinion, people there are free to mock/disagree with you. But expressing such an opinion here on SO is probably not appropriate, just as it isn't appropriate to stand up in a movie theatre and express your feelings about who should be the next president. Whether closing the question was a mistake or not is irrelevant. The system worked just as designed: it got reopened.

Comment: As Cody said, voicing your opinion is fine (on meta). Calling people who work with this site the way it's designed to work "SO police" isn't here, especially when you're referencing a post where the asker refers to people who voted to close as "nobodies" and was otherwise rude. If my opinion was that someone was really wrong, and the correct solution for their lack of knowledge was to suggest an inappropriate act involving their mother, that might be my opinion on the matter; it doesn't belong here, though. Both you and the asker resorting to name calling isn't appropriate for either of you.

Comment: @KenWhite I think that the "love it or leave it" is more destructive than name calling.

Answer (score 3):

No. A sufficiently determined attacker would simply host your process in a VM and break in that way.

Besides, you don't need to attach a debugger to attack a program: grabbing a minidump will let an adversary inspect the memory state offline, or using [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) you can inspect open handles to determine what files are vulnerable.

If you were going to use an exception to determine whether a naive debugger were attached, I'd personally use `INT_MIN/-1` to trigger an integer overflow exception. Most don't know about that one.

Comment: It should be noted that it's actually non-trivial (in C) to perform a division by zero or `INT_MIN/-1`. Since it's UB, as long as the compiler can detect at compile-time that it would happen, it's free to optimize it out or do whatever it likes... You often need to jump through some hoops to hide the behavior from the compiler if you actually want the instruction to be executed by the cpu...

Comment: On x86, the same exception (#DE) will be generated for both division by 0 and INT_MIN/-1.

Comment: @R..: you store either the numerator or denominator in a volatile variable and most compilers generate code for division.